# Exporting tables from 30 databases

Tags: performance, mysql, go

What my code do:

1. Connecting to 30 DB (consistently)
2. Copying DB file to temp.dat
3. Reading temp.dat
4. Writing read data to file

So, it connects 30 times with different databases. This take 6-7 second (on a powerful notebook), but if I run this code on notebook / PC with low hardware specifications these take more than 20 seconds. How can I speed this up?

```
func fileCopyProcedure(ptSource string, ptDest string) {
    sourceFile, err := os.Open(ptSource)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer sourceFile.Close()

    destFile, err := os.Create(ptDest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer destFile.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(destFile, sourceFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    err = destFile.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    sourceFileInfo, err := sourceFile.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    destFileInfo, err := destFile.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if sourceFileInfo.Size() == destFileInfo.Size() {
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}

func DB_Handler(path string) {
    var db *sql.DB

    err := fileCopyProcedure(path, "tmp.dat")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    db, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", "tmp.dat")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("select cr_value, fx_value, orm_value, speend_value, sc_source_value, datainfo, secure_only from cookies")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var sql_cr_value string
        var sql_fx_value string
        var sql_orm_value string
        var sql_speend_value string
        var sql_sc_source_value string
        var sql_datainfo string
        var sql_secure_only string

        err = rows.Scan(
            &sql_cr_value,
            &sql_fx_value,
            &sql_orm_value,
            &sql_speend_value,
            &sql_sc_source_value,
            &sql_datainfo,
            &sql_secure_only,
        )

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if sql_cr_value != "" && sql_orm_value != "" && sql_datainfo != "" {
            var cprInfo = fmt.Sprintf("%s   %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\r\n",
                sql_cr_value,
                sql_fx_value,
                sql_orm_value,
                sql_speend_value,
                sql_sc_source_value,
                sql_datainfo,
                sql_secure_only,
            )

            var hkInfo = fmt.Sprintf("%s\r\n",
                sql_datainfo,
            )

            wfile, err := os.OpenFile(
                "data.txt",
                os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600,
            )

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer wfile.Close()

            if _, err = wfile.WriteString(cprInfo); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            wfile, err = os.OpenFile(
                "opx.txt",
                os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600,
            )

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer wfile.Close()

            if _, err = wfile.WriteString(hkInfo); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

        }
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a question, why you're never return the error?

Comment: @MarioSantini return err? In general I use the recover() function in order to my program does not be exit/close at the first error

Comment: @MarioSantini and why i need to return ??

Comment: your function signature show an error as a return value, but you just return nil at the end and when you find an error you printout. Just want to understand why. Because in some case you should take decisions when incounter certain errors.

Comment: @MarioSantini oh, u say the right think, i remove this method :) but just for me this cannot be play a role.

Comment: Question: Why store the database in a temp file, as opposed to just concatenating it to the end of the result file?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix because this database used an another program, and i can not be edit this databased, thus for this need to copy to temp file

Comment: Don't copy the temp file... just concatenate it. Add it to the end of the *single* resulting file. Doing such an operation shouldn't modify the original database.

Comment: [sqlite can dump data directly to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables)

Comment: @FreezePhoenix how can i do this?

Comment: @tramway I think sineemore answered that question.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix i forgot add: i use a windows 8.1, but no Linux

Comment: @tramway, you've posted code that works with a single database. It's perfectly fine (in terms of perfomance), and I don't see a chance to speed this particular piece of code. If I understand correctly there is more code involved, that may have perfomance issues. Also I may be better to use sqlite dump functionality if it is availiable in your enviroment.